# How to read multiple xml elements from a file?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmldocument

Hi all i have this xml document and i want to extract either the first or the second applications file path and file name etc. ive tried

```
DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/InstallerList/Installer/File_Path").InnerText
```

But i only ever get the first applications info and never the second, ive tried playing around with

```
DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//Installer")
```

and adding a integer to the end of it so i could cycle through however it doesnt seem to like that. Any thoughts?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<InstallerList>
 <Installer Name="First Application">
   <FilePath>C:\</FilePath>
   <Third_Parameter>etc</Third_Parameter>
   <Forth_Parameter>etc</Forth_Parameter>
 </Installer>
 <Installer Name="Second Application">
   <FilePath>etc</FilePath>
   <Third_Parameter>etc</Third_Parameter>
   <Forth_Parameter>etc</Forth_Parameter>
 </Installer>
</InstallerList>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select just a single `FilePath` element, given some known key value, such as the installer's `Name` attribute, you can add a condition to your XPath to narrow the results, like this:

```
DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/InstallerList/Installer[@Name='First Application']/FilePath").InnerText
```

Or, you can simply select all of the `FilePath` elements, and then loop through them, like this:

```
For Each node As XmlNode In DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/InstallerList/Installer/FilePath")
    Dim path As String = node.InnerText
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: ok thanks for your help for starters and when i try DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/InstallerList/Installer[@Name="+app+"]/FilePath").InnerText where app is a string containing the contents of the Name attribute i get a Expression must evaluate to a node-set error any thoughts?

Comment: It worked for me.  Did you forget the opening and closing single quotes around the value of `app`?